# error 404 with mod_proxy and redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, plesk, mod-proxy

I am trying to achieve a redirection by keeping the existing url in the address bar. I am somehow achieve it, but no matter in which page I redirect I receive error 404. I have mod_proxy and proxy_http enabled. Here is my htaccess code:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://demo.example.com/$1 [P]
```

Any ideas? My server is vps with plesk and I have access to any  conf file if needed

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-042stab120.5 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Fri Nov 11 19:59:21 2016 from adsl-152.176.58.250.tellas.gr
root@lvps92-51-132-79:~# curl -vv http://gazzetta.edentalbook.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://gazzetta.edentalbook.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 92.51.132.79...
* Connected to gazzetta.edentalbook.com (92.51.132.79) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: gazzetta.edentalbook.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sun, 13 Nov 2016 20:59:19 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://demo.edentalbook.com
< X-Powered-By: PleskLin
< MS-Author-Via: DAV
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=62hctjah1g95c33lprkk2q9m50; expires=Sun, 20-Nov-2016 20:59:19 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Powered-By: PleskLin
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
```

Comment: can you try running a verbose 'curl' request against your site and pasting the output here with your question? like this:  curl -vv <your site here>

Comment: @melgart where do I need to run this? inside htaccess? in php code or in terminal?

Comment: sorry, in a terminal. this will show a more verbose request to your site

Comment: @melgart just edited

Answer (score 0):

It looks like HTTP header "Host" in request is transmitted but don't match on server.

You can [reset this header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) by:

```
Header set Host "demo.edentalbook.com"
```

Or add domain alias `gazzetta.edentalbook.com` to domain `demo.edentalbook.com` where it hosted.